# Conditionally factor values

Tags: function, openoffice-calc

I have the below sheet in OpenOffice:

[image: SO34228017 question example]

I need to multiply the values in the first column by let's say `0.75`, but only if the value is not `0` or `-1`. I then need to do the same to the values at the end of a custom algorithm string (for use with a Magento plugin) in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally multiplying by a value is fairly straightforward.  Let's say your "Shipping Price" column is Column A, you'll put this formula in the column you want the new values to be shown in:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>0;A2<>-1);A2*0.75;A2)
```

Standard `IF(This Condition Is True ; Then Do This ; Else Do This Other Thing)`  where "This Condition" is "A2 does not equal 0 AND A2 does not equal -1".

Instead of hard-typing in 0.75, you could put your "multiply by" value in a certain cell and refer to that cell in the formula.  If you do this make sure to put the `$` symbol before the column letter and row number, so they won't change when you copy and paste.  Copy and paste the formula down however far your data goes.

For multiplying the values at the end of the string (let's say your "Algorithm" column is column B), if you just want the values:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>0;A2<>-1);0.75*VALUE(RIGHT(B2;4));0)
```

Same IF formula construction, with the addition of pulling the rightmost four characters off the string with the RIGHT function, converting them from a string into a number with the VALUE function, then doing the multiplication.

If you want the new values at the end of the string, you could do it with a helper column.  Lets say the calculation was done in column E:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>0;A2<>-1);CONCATENATE(LEFT(B2;LEN(B2)-4);LEFT(E2;4));B2)
```

If A2 is not 0 AND not -1, then take the left side of the string in B2 minus four characters and concatenate it with the leftmost four characters (a dollar value, the decimal point, and two number after the decimal point) of the multiplication done in column E.  Else, just repeat the string from B2.

If you don't want the helper column, the string could be made all in one formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>0;A2<>-1);CONCATENATE(LEFT(B2;LEN(B2)-4);LEFT(IF(AND(A2<>0;A2<>-1);0.75*VALUE(RIGHT(B2;4));"");4));B2)
```